# Double Ducky (or Fu-two-shiki)

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

There are two* logical, discrete ways to solve this Futoshiki puzzle, each with its own unique solution. You can solve it using the letters given, or use the numbers 1-5, but if you map the letters to numbers, there must be a justification for how you map them (ie. you can't arbitrarily assign a letter to a number). The rules of Futoshiki are:

1. Each row and column must contain one of each digit from 1-5 (or letter in "DUCKY").
2. All inequality constraints between boxes must be satisfied (ie. 1 < 5; you'll have to figure out what the comparison between letters is depending on which route you take).

[image: futoshiki board]

Here is a [penpa-edit](https://rjrudman.github.io/penpa-edit/?m=solve&p=pVJNa+MwEL37Z+g8Ac14/CEftx+n0kPbpSzGhMC6IRDirtuwxCb/PU9yQqC1TmXi0fN70Ysmeh//9qu+JXbkKC3JEqOK3OIFWJ1/ktpCQDVJbVJDRvCwaZJxeKrGYVnVzZGG31f4XI3oj9VoWNVUtTEw9TvActD+QMu8dLG+VENm1ffd/+Vbt+/bv+t2+cuQgC0Y31Yym12LI283nweYej6N8A68fOfLiE8Z8SkjPs7zmOorzzYm5JFf4NgI7LwwYyU2JnAxbyUSE1Jvlc4JkTlEYzt0dgdu+z7cuYT+gojQkIZ+G7r13bx328O628EB1APikSplODT++qyg0gbkM+lnB8RKLPmEJfc5nbDPbCETLgTJzibsMhIuA8ZKogiCx8okOaIoONxdOOJr6DehK/oxSWrFjlB6XlE/ovRMKC3Y4SW/fhaKyZoT) (without the letters entered in case you want to use numbers instead), and here is a transcription:

```
[ ] [ ] [D] [ ] [ ]  
 v   v           ^   
[ ] [ ] [U]<[ ] [ ]  
                     
[D] [U] [C] [K] [Y]
 v                   
[ ] [ ] [K] [ ]<[ ]
                 v   
[ ]>[ ] [Y] [ ]<[ ]
```

A full answer of both solutions is preferable, but if you want to submit a partial answer of only one solution, I will accept the other solution (since it was left to last, it seems that it was harder), if that makes sense.

*Technically, there are three, but two of these methods are simply "inverses" of each other, so only one of them will count.

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that the title is a spoonerism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Solution**

We can try the following

> Assign the letters to numbers depending on the order in which they appear in the alphabet (C=1, D=2, K=3, U=4, Y=5)

Step 1

> First we can fill in the Cs in a unique way.
>  [image]

Step 2

> The inequalities in the bottom right force some letters which gives us some more of the rest of the grid.
>  [image]

Step 3

> Noticing that the top of the fourth column must be a U we find that the rest of the grid solves quite quickly.
>  [image]

**Second Solution**

I have also noticed that

> If we look at the Scrabble scores of D,U,C,K,Y we get D=2, U=1, C=3, K=5, Y=4, so maybe this will lead to a solution

Step 1

> We can fill in all of the Us quickly
>  [image]

Step 2

> The bottomright corner then resolves pretty quickly (the last two squares in the right column cannot contain K or Y so must contain C and D) and we can fill in a bit more of the grid using that.
>  [image]

Step 3

> Now the bottom left is filled in in just one way and we can easily finish from here.
>  [image]

Hence, we have two valid and different solutions motivated by different aspects of the letters.

Comment: I saw you were on the right track with the rot13(fpenooyr fpberf) but your original solution wasn't quite right. I was tempted to give you a nudge in the right direction in case someone else found the second solution from your original answer and then I'd have to wrestle with which one to accept, now I have nothing to worry about! :)

Comment: @samm82 Yeah, sorry about that, I first misread one of the inequalities and then convinced myself it didn't work. I think I was just very tired yesterday.